# Melhor banco de dados para aplicação Android

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sql-server, android-studio, sqlite

Galera, estou com um duvida em qual banco escolher para uma aplicação android: Sql Server ou Sqlite?
Tenho um pequeno Crawler, que não necessita ser executado toda vez, apenas uma vez, e quando houver alguma atualização, que acontece raramente.

Comment: Se for um banco externo depende do conhecimento que você tem, com banco de dados que vai utilizar. A dica é usar o que você tem mais experiência.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Banco interno do android só tem o SQLite(para pequenas necessidades, como um jogo simples).
Se é banco externo(para grandes necessidades, como uma comunidade), então pode ser mySql ou sql server. Vai da sua necessidade.

Para bancos externos, você pode tentar usar alternativas gratuítas, como o google firebase, que é um banco nosql.

Comment: Essa resposta está claramente errada.